# Is there an online alternative for picasa?

Tags: images, database

Is there an installable PHP/MySQL image database system like Picasa? I want to setup a small image database for our company.

It would be hosted online, so the co-workers have access from any place. I dont need the complete features of Picasa, simple storing, tagging, preview (with thumbs) and download (maybe as ZIPped packages) would be sufficient.

EDIT for clarification: Actually, I am neither searching for a photo sharing service like flickr nor for a gallery. Although it should be possible to use the both of them in a way I'd like to. Well, I am not really sure.

The truth is: I already had coded a system for myself. But this was years ago and far from state-of-the-art. It works, but it is not very user-friendly. That's why I'm searching for an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Picasa 'is' online... You can keep it closed for the public as well. It is as close as it gets to picasa! ;)

- http://gallery.menalto.com/  Good alternative

Comment: +1 for the Gallery mention.  it is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This wikipedia article for [Photo sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_sharing) contains a discussion on the subject
It also points to this article comparing many such sharing sites : [List of photo sharing websites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_photo_sharing_websites).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Coppermine Photo Gallery](http://coppermine-gallery.net/).

You can install it on your own server and has a plenty of features. I am using it now for more than a year for personal/family-photos on my server and I am very satisfied with the Coppermine Photo Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of different Online Photo Galleries. I didnt care for Picasa, as I wanted more control with options, plugins, and host my own photos.  I was on Zenith Photo Gallery for a long time, but development stopped.  I went back and tried Coppermine again, plus a few others. In the end, I went with [Gallery 2](http://gallery.menalto.com/).

Gallery offers a lot of plugins (Just dont use the beta version 3).  It takes a little bit to figure out all the options and themes, but you can make a really nice photo album site with it.  They have really good album/photo security, so you can control which users/groups have access.